# How to export results of a SQL query ran on Teradata to a external JSON file?

Tags: json, database, teradata, etl

I am running a query on Teradata and the large(400M rows) result set needs to be exported to a JSON file.

As the data volume is huge and we need faster response, I cant use BTEQ. Fast Export doesn't support JSON_AGG function. Hence I am left with Teradata Parallel Transporter. But I am not sure how to use TPT to export result set in a JSON format. Any help will be appreciated.

Sample SQL Code:

```
SELECT 
A1.ID_DATE,
A1.UPC,
A1.STORE_ID,
A1.NET_QTY,
A1.UNITS_SOLD,
A1.COST_AMT
FROM 
MSI_VW.V_FACT_SALES_ORD A1
JOIN 
MSI_VW.V_DIM_DATE A2
ON A1.ID_DATE = A2.ID_DATE
AND A2.WKS_FRM_TODAY BETWEEN -52 AND -1
```

Expected JSON File:

```
[
  {
    ID_DATE: 4/3/2019,
    UPC: 22000363,
    STORE_ID: 370,
    NET_QTY: 3,
    UNITS_SOLD: 3,
    COST_AMT: 12
  },
  {
    ID_DATE: 4/4/2019,
    UPC: 22002333,
    STORE_ID: 210,
    NET_QTY: 4,
    UNITS_SOLD: 3,
    COST_AMT: 11
  },
  .
  .
  .
]
```

Comment: 400,000,000 rows, i.e. way over 40GB, as a single JSON? Don't do it.

Comment: @dnoeth And for smaller data sets, what would be the best way to export them as JSON?